# Enable IIS using Powershell SDK and C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to enable IIS using Poweshell SDK in C sharp . My code is as follows.

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInst = PowerShell.Create())
            {
              
                PowerShellInst.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process; Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole");
                Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInst.Invoke();

                if (PowerShellInst.HadErrors)
                {

                    foreach (var error in PowerShellInst.Streams.Error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (PSObject obj in PSOutput)
                    {
                        if (obj != null)
                        {
                            Console.Write(obj);
                           

                        }
                    }
                }

                PowerShellInst.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Output is

```
 Microsoft.Dism.Commands.ImageObject
```

When I execute same command using powershell  then output is as follows

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to get output like this?

Note: google cloud shell when installing or upgrading on windows via command line shows such output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use PSObject properties to access to that information. You can iterate through ***PSObject.Properties*** like this.

```
foreach (var property in obj.Properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " : " + property.Value);
}
```